# I have 2 arrays on 2 diferent selects, when the value is change on the first one, the other one needs to change to the same position

Tags: php, html, mysql, dynamic

Basically I am new to PHP I am a frontend developer trying new stuff.

I have a form that gets data from a Database table and it has 2 selects (date and type_session) both has for example 3 values each (for now, this value is dynamic, for now its only a test to explain)

date:
01-02-2022
02-02-2022
03-02-2022

type_session:
in_person
e_learning
b_learning

So my question is, how can I check if the user swaps the date and then swap the type_session accordingly with PHP?

```
 <select name="select_date_cronograma" id="select_date_cronograma">
              <?php
               if ($cronograma_accao->num_rows()>0){
               foreach ($cronograma_accao->result() as $row){
               ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row->$row->date; ?>"><?php echo $row->date; ?></option>
              <?php
              }
             }
            ?>
```

```
    

       <select name="select_type_cronograma" id="select_type_cronograma">
               <?php
                 if ($cronograma_accao->num_rows()>0){
                  foreach ($cronograma_accao->result() as $row){
               ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $row->type_session; ?>"><?php echo $row->type_session; ?></option>
               <?php
              }
             }
           ?>
```

Comment: you wouldn't do this with PHP, you would do this with javascript

Comment: hmm, yeah thats make sense, but how can I control a php variable with javascript? I mean I won't use the variable just use the value right? @ysth So everything that I need to use Dynamically I just use JavaScript, I have other problems that this question would help

Comment: now it sounds like you are asking something other than how to just change what's selectd in one dropdown when the other is changed, which has nothing to do with php variables, at least until the form is submitted.  but I don't know what it is you are asking.

Comment: Basically am creating 2 select boxes, and presenting the values with PHP, how can I change the value of the 2nd select box with javascript is the variable that gives the value of both selects are from PHP?  @ysth

Comment: Use JS to detect the first one being changed, and send an AJAX request to the server to fetch values for the second one (based on the selected value in the first), that will trigger some PHP which returns the options to put into the second select. This technique is called "cascading dropdowns" - you can find lots of tutorials etc about it online already

Comment: @ADyson thanks, I will look in to that, but I don't anything about AJAX, will need to learn a lot.

Comment: But...if the option you want to change the second to is already in the select from the beginning, then it's correct that you don't need any AJAX or PHP - in that case you can simply use Javascript to change the selected value. From your description it wasn't clear whether that was the case or not.

Comment: it sounds almost like you think php is running while the user is interacting with the form.  it isn't; a php request generates the form, then the user interacts with the browser, and if they submit the form (or you do ajax requests) that is a new php request.